# Mysql to use the same table row in two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Notifications where status=1 is EntryTime and status=2 is ExitTime.

```
  +-----+------+------+------+--------+
  | n_id| notification_time   | status | 
  +-----+------+------+------+--------+
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 16:44:02 |   2    |
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 16:43:55 |   1    |
  |  2  | 2016-11-17 13:05:47 |   1    |
  |  2  | 2016-11-17 13:08:29 |   2    |
  |  4  | 2016-11-17 14:09:02 |   1    |
  |  4  | 2016-11-17 14:13:45 |   2    |
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 22:05:02 |   1    |
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 22:09:12 |   2    |
  +----+------+------+-------+---------+
```

I would need a result like

```
  +-----+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
  | n_id| Entry_time          | Exit_time               | 
  +-----+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 16:43:55 |   2016-11-17 16:44:02   |
  |  2  | 2016-11-17 13:05:47 |   2016-11-17 13:08:29   |
  |  4  | 2016-11-17 14:09:02 |   2016-11-17 14:13:45   | 
  |  1  | 2016-11-17 22:05:02 |   2016-11-17 22:09:12   |
  +----+------+------+-------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: you can group and show the min and max by id

Comment: You have two time n_id = 1 (4 entries )  is correct?

Comment: good question. If you have more than 2 entries by id, the min() and max() doesn't will help

Comment: Yes, n_id could be repetitive. I have another primary key column which i haven't mentioned in the tabular data above.

Comment: well add the other primary key  or the rules for join the correct rows -

Comment: the @scaisEdge inner join will do your need then.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to group:

```
select n_id
    , min(notification_time) as entry_time
    , max(notification_time) as exit_time
from Notifications
group by n_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have always a couple of distinct n_id you can use a sellf join based on alias

```
  select a.n_id, a.notification_time as Entry_time, a.notification_time as Exit_time
  from my_table a 
  inner join my_table b on a.n_id = b.n_id
  where a.status = 1
  and b.status = 2
```

if n_id is repetitive  need  others column for correct match between rows